# Standard way to treat a zipfile as a site directory?

Tags: python, zip, packaging

I'm trying to package up a script including its dependencies into an executable zip file, following basically the following steps:

```
$ mkdir build
$ pip install --target build -r requirements.txt
$ cp -r mypackage build
$ echo 'from mypackage import main; main()' > build/__main__.py
$ cd build
$ zip -r myscript-with-dependencies.zip *
$ echo '#!/usr/bin/env python' | cat - myscript-with-dependencies.zip \
    >../dist/myscript
```

This works, in general, except that `.pth` files don't seem to be evaled: they're ignored by [`site.addsitedir(zip_path)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.addsitedir) (probably because [it doesn't seem to have been written to understand zip files](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3c58fa7dc7f1/Lib/site.py#l172)).

This is specifically a problem for *me* because some of my dependencies use setuptools [namespace-packages](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#namespace-packages), and its magic happens mostly within `.pth` files.

Before I go off and write something like `addzipsitedir` I was wondering if anyone has experience with this kind of problem, am I something obvious? In general the [zipimport docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) don't say much beyond "it just works!". (Which, again, it mostly does, except for namespace packages and things installed into eggs, etc.)

Comment: You cannot merge the namespaced eggs into one directory structure?

Comment: I can indeed, but I'd like a solution that is more general (and doesn't require *different* Makefile hacks every time I want to package a new project or add a new dependency.)

Comment: That's the work-around I'd think about in any case. :-)

Comment: And it's probably easier than writing `addzipsitedir`, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `addsitedir()` does not handle zip files; but it should be easy enough to replicate the behavior.

See the [`site.addsitedir()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/site.py#l172) source code; the code simply attempts to call `os.listdir()` on the path to then discover `.pth` files:

```
try:
    names = os.listdir(sitedir)
except os.error:
    return
dotpth = os.extsep + "pth"
names = [name for name in names if name.endswith(dotpth)]
for name in sorted(names):
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
```

where `addpackage()` is just `site.addpackage()`. You can replace the above `names` listing with a listing of `.pth` files inside of your zipfile. You'll have to replicate the [`site.addpackage()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/site.py#l131) behaviour as well, that function expects to be able to read the `.pth` file.

Simplified, that function does:

```
with f:
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
        if line.startswith("#"):
            continue
        if line.startswith(("import ", "import\t")):
            exec line
            continue
        line = line.rstrip()
        dir, dircase = makepath(sitedir, line)
        if not dircase in known_paths and os.path.exists(dir):
            sys.path.append(dir)
            known_paths.add(dircase)
```

with exception handling mixed in. `makepath()` is `site.makepath()`, and `known_paths` ensures that any path found is only added once.

So, in essence, all items named by `.pth` are added to your `sys.path` but anything starting with `import` is executed there and then, giving the `.pth` file a hook into the `site.py` loading stage.

The `import` hook is used by `setuptools`-based packages to build the namespaced packages; here is one from a package in the `zc` namespace:

```
import sys,types,os; p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('zc',)); ie = os.path.exists(os.path.join(p,'__init__.py')); m = not ie and sys.modules.setdefault('zc',types.ModuleType('zc')); mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]); (p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
```

It creates an empty module object in `sys.modules` using the `sitedir` local variable from the `addpackage()` function. Note the `os.path.exists()` call; for zipped eggs this will fail (not add the empty module object), so you may need to detect namespaced packages and come up with your own version for these. Any package in the `zc` namespace just ensures there is a `ModuleType()` object for the parent namespaces it cares about, with a `__path__` attribute pointing to `{sitedir}/{packagename}/__init__.py`.

The other alternative is to merge the namespaced packages into one directory structure instead.