# Python compile all modules into a single python file

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python to be sent to other people, who are running the same python version, however these some 3rd party modules that need to be installed to use it.

Is there a way to compile into a .pyc (I only say pyc because its a python compiled file) that has the all the dependant modules inside it as well?

So they can run the programme without needing to install the modules separately?

Edit:
Sorry if it wasnt clear, but I am aware of things such as cx_freeze etc but what im trying to is just a single python file.

So they can just type "python myapp.py" and then it will run. No installation of anything. As if all the module codes are in my .py file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on **python 2.3 or later** and your dependencies are **pure python**:

If you don't want to go the setuptools or distutiles routes, you can provide a zip file with the pycs for your code and all of its dependencies.  You will have to do [a little work to make any complex pathing inside the zip file available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388944/standard-way-to-treat-a-zipfile-as-a-site-directory) (if the dependencies are just lying around at the root of the zip this is not necessary. Then just add the zip location to your path and it should work just as if the dependencies files has been installed.

If your dependencies include .pyds or other binary dependencies you'll probably have to fall back on distutils.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include .pyc files for the libraries required, but no - .pyc cannot work as a container for multiple files (unless you will collect all the source into one .py file and then compile it).

Comment: I only say .pyc because thats what I know of, but maybe theres an alternative? Without using something like cx_freeze etc. Just need the whole python programme with dependencies in one file basically. (If its possible?)

Comment: Everything is possible given enough manpower. You could for example compile your script into standalone executable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're after is the ability for your end users to run one command, e.g. `install my_custom_package_and_all_required_dependencies`, and have it assemble everything it needs.

This is a perfect use case for [distutils](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html), with which you can make manifests for your own code that link out to external dependencies. If your 3rd party modules are available publicly in a standard format (they should be, and if they're not, it's pretty easy to package them yourself), then this approach has the benefit of allowing you to very easily change what versions of 3rd party libraries your code runs against (see [this section](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) of the above linked doc). If you're dead set on packaging others' code with your own, you can always include the required files in the `.egg` you create with distutils.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. build a package that will install the dependencies for them (I don't recommend this if the only dependencies are python packages that are installed with pip)
2. Use [virtual environments](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).  You use an existing python on their system but python modules are installed into the virtualenv.

or I suppose you could just punt, and create a shell script that installs them, and tell them to run it once before they run your stuff.